# Groupby function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset of car sales. (I am beginner to data science, so it is arbitary data for asking query.)

```
car_sales = pd.DataFrame({'Make':['BMW','Nissan','Toyota'], 'Color':['White','Black','Grey'], 'Odometer':[8000,4000,9000], 'Price':[4000,5000,6000]})
```

If I want to group columns of the car sales DataFrame by the Make column and find the average,

I am using code as follows:

```
car_sales.groupby(['Make']).mean()
```

But it is showing me error:
TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]

This same syntax is run in video lecture I am taking, but my notebook is showing type error.

Comment: It is a pandas version issue.
use following code : `car_sales.groupby(['Make']).mean(numeric_only=True)`

Answer (score 2):

Error is coming as you are doing mean on all columns and Color column is of object data type, to solve this issue either you can use the approach by Panda Kim and Nimantha Fernando. There is one more approach i.e. (use of agg() with groupby) with which you can use other methods as well extensively.

```html
car_sales = pd.DataFrame({'Make':['BMW','Nissan','Toyota'], 'Color':['White','Black','Grey'], 'Odometer':[8000,4000,9000], 'Price':[4000,5000,6000]}) 

car_sales.groupby('Make').agg({'Odometer': 'mean', 'Price': 'mean'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas version issue.
TRY

```
`car_sales.groupby(['Make']).mean(numeric_only=True)`
```

Answer (score 0):

the error you are getting is caused by mean() function trying to calculate the mean of all columns in your data frame including the non-numeric columns. For calculating the mean, you need to  select those columns first and then apply the `groupby()` and `mean()` operations.

```
selected_columns = car_sales[['Odometer', 'Price']]

selected_columns.groupby(car_sales['Make']).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by Nimantha Fernando the error you are getting is caused by mean() function trying to calculate the mean of all columns in your data frame including the non-numeric columns. For calculating the mean, you need to select those columns first and then apply the groupby() and mean() operations.

```
selected_columns = car_sales[["Odometer", "Doors"]]

selected_columns.groupby(car_sales['Make']).mean()
```

**Else use filter**

Filter the Columns which are not int type and apply groupby() and mean() function to filtered data.

```
car_sales.filter(items= ["Make", "Doors", "Odometer"]).groupby("Make").mean( )
```